# RethinkDB does not create help and help_internal databases

Tags: rethinkdb, horizon

I am trying to use the Horizon framework by the RethinkDB team but I am facing startup issues with Rethink. I try to start up the server with the command

`rethinkdb --http-port 8082`

all works fine but when I run my app.js where horizon is embedded, I obtain the error.

`error: Connection to RethinkDB terminated: Error: The database help_internal does not exist.Run hz set-schema to initialize the database, then start the Horizon server.`

I ran the command above and it creates a rethinkdb_data folder and whenever I restart the server, it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell `hz set-schema` how to connect to the RethinkDb server you're running, otherwise it will create its own in your current working directory.  You can pass it the same connection options you pass to `hz serve`.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error. It can be confusing because in dev mode of horizon it usually creates these databases for you.

In prod, however, you must create the databases yourself. To do this it is as simple as logging into RethinkDB's admin interface, click on the "Tables" navigation item then clicking the "+ Add Database" button. Create two databases called 'help' and 'help_internal' assuming that your horizon project_name name is 'help'.

Note that in addition to creating the databases I've described you may also need to create tables in these databases. This is where you should use get-schema on your dev server (to dump the current schema to disk) and set-schema on your prod server (to create the tables needed to support the schema).

For some npm tasks that accomplish the getting and setting of schema you can see [here](https://github.com/jimthedev/react-webpack-horizon/blob/master/package.json#L12).

Comment: I actually got this running by executing `hz schema apply --start-rethinkdb no --connect #:# .hz/schema.toml`. The reason this used to fail for me is that I was already running a rethinkdb server and didn't specify the `start-rethinkdb no` flag. After doing this the schema is successfully applied.